# Put together two counters with different conditions

Tags: sql, join, count, group-by

I need to count all `tweets` and `retweets`(all retweets are also a tweets) foreach user in table `authors`. My first idea works pretty well:

**Tweets counter**

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, count(*)
FROM authors AS a
INNER JOIN tweets AS t 
ON t.fromuser_id = a.id
GROUP BY a.id, a.name
ORDER BY count(*)
```

**Retweets counter**

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, count(*)
FROM authors AS a
INNER JOIN tweets AS t 
ON t.fromuser_id = a.id AND retweet = TRUE
GROUP BY a.id, a.name
ORDER BY count(*)
```

...but now i want to put that all together. I wonder if there's a better (faster) way than that:

**Merged**

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, count(*), (
    SELECT count(*) 
    FROM tweets 
    WHERE fromuser_id = a.id AND retweet = TRUE
)
FROM authors AS a
INNER JOIN tweets AS t 
ON t.fromuser_id = a.id
GROUP BY a.id, a.name
ORDER BY count(*)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way.  Use conditional summation:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, count(*),
       sum(case when retweet = true then 1 else 0 end) as retweets
FROM authors AS a
INNER JOIN tweets AS t 
ON t.fromuser_id = a.id
GROUP BY a.id, a.name
ORDER BY count(*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, count(*),
       SUM(CASE WHEN retweet = TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as retweets_count
FROM authors AS a
INNER JOIN tweets AS t 
ON t.fromuser_id = a.id
GROUP BY a.id, a.name
ORDER BY count(*)
```